# detecting a key pressed and key released event

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

The following function is called whenever keypress event occurs:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

   printf("Key is pressed !\n");
   // If key pressed down,call function A
   // If key released , call function B
}
```

How do I detect these events ?

The key pressed could be any key from a *window keyboard*.I just want to know whether a key was pressed or was released after pressing. How do I do this ?

Comment: You have to use TWO different messages: WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP

Comment: You can find plenty of examples of how to do this on the web by searching for keylogger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
     if ( nCode >= 0 )
     {
         if ( wParam == WM_KEYDOWN  || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN )
         {
             functionA();
         }
         else
         {
             functionB();
         }
     }
     return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between _WM_KEYDOWN_ and _WM_SYSKEYDOWN_ ?

Comment: and it has been working fine without `return CallNextHookEx(handleKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);`

Comment: WM_SYSKEYDOWN is returned for some keys, for example, F10 - I think from historical reasons.

Comment: I don't suggest you to remove CallNextHookEx from this function - results are undefined.

Comment: After I have run some of the things are not normal ! Like I cannot see the run dialog when I press win+r !

Comment: I don't know what exactly you do in these functions.